# Is it possible to join two entities with panache?

Tags: quarkus-panache, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

I want to get two values from two different sql tables.

In sql we would do "Select a.value, b.value from A a inner join B b on a.id = b.id where ..."

Is it possible to do it with panache? Like join two entities or something like that?

Can't really find much about joins with quarkus panache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Panache doesn't have any specific way to deal with joins.

You can still load specific fields using HQL and projections:

```java
List<EntitiesView> results = EntityA
    .find("Select a.value, b.value from A a inner join B b on a.id = b.id where ...")
    .project(EntitiesView.class)
    .list();
```

Where `EntitiesView` is:

```java
@RegisterForReflection 
class EntitiesView {
   public final Object valueA;
   public final Object valueB;

   public EntitiesView(Object valueA, Object valueB) {
       this.valueA = valueA;
       this.valueB = valueB;
   }
}
```

You can find [more details about projections](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#query-projection) on the Panache guide.